# Error when using CDI and OSGI

Tags: java, netbeans, jsf-2, cdi

I'm trying to develop a simple login form with JSF, Glassfish, OSGI and CDI. This is the source code:
http://www.2shared.com/file/45Jdr1iu/NetBeansProjects.html
The problem is that when I add beans.xml file into WEB-INF directory I get this error stack into Glassfish log file.

http://pastebin.com/3KX5ir90

It's very important to fix this CDI issue because I get NPE when I try to call method from the OSGI bundle. When I try to open the page from the web browser I get empty page.

Would you help me to find the problem so I can fix it, please?

Best wishes, 
Peter

Comment: I removed "@SessionScoped" from the bean and everything works well. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few exceptions, one of them is a ClassNotFoundException, probably has something to do with the scopes and visibility in your OSGI bundle (I'm not an OSGI expert, FYI). I also saw a NonSerializableException towards the bottom too. Meaning you have a bean that is in a scope that must be serializable (SessionScoped or ConversationScoped most likely) which has a member that isn't serializable or transient.

Comment: Yes you're right. If I remove @SessionScoped it works, but how I can fix this problem?

Comment: The serialization problem or the visibility problem?